# Modeling for probability of event and amount of event

Tags: regression, classification

I have built a logistic regression model to predict the probability that the event for my dataset occurs.

I also want to know the predicted amount (a regression problem) associated with that event (a customer buying my product).

Incumbent with the logistic model is including event and non-event outcomes. Is the same true for a regression (not classification) problem? Should I include in my linear model customers who didn't buy another product (and thus spent 0 dollars)? Or would that be sort of "double-dipping" if I went to multiply the likelihood * amount for an expected value of a given customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using a sequence of prediction models to 1: predict whether or not a product is purchased (binary outcome) then 2: if consumer buys product, predict quantity/volume purchased. The second model is referred to as a conditional model, since you are conditioning on the fact that some quantity/volume of product is purchased. It makes sense to train the second model using only the subset of the training dataset that purchased products. You should inspect a number of measures to assess both models 1 and 2 as well as their overall performance to decide whether the predictive accuracy is acceptable.

Comment: Rats, you beat me by 2 minutes. That's what I get for answering such a new question.

Comment: Goodness of fit can be badly biased as a measure of predictive accuracy, though. Did you mean looking at goodness of fit inside cross-validation? We wouldn't usually call that "fit", I think.

Comment: @Kodiologist thanks for the suggested edit. I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to predict the amount spent rather than just whether any amount is spent at all, logistic regression won't cut it. You want a model in which the amount itself is a dependent variable, such as linear regression. If lots of subjects don't buy anything, a zero-inflated model could be helpful. You can keep using logistic regression if you use a two-stage compound model in which you predict whether subjects buy anything, then, among those for whom you predicted a purchase, predict the actual amount spent with another model.

Comment: I must not have been clear above. I have two models: 1) logistic for the likelihood of buying and 2) linear for predicting the *continuous* amount spent. My plan is to do the compound model - I was just checking whether I should exclude from my continuous-variable modeling exercise those customers who didn't spent anything (the $0s).

Comment: @blacksite Oh, I see. Yes, because in practice the second part will only see subjects who you predicted to not spend any money, you should train it with only the nonzeros, like AdamO said.